# Constructing matrices out of span

Tags: matrices, category-theory

> Let $A,B$ be sets, and let $\require{AMScd}$
>   \begin{CD}
>     A @<<< R\\
>     & @VV V\\
>       && B
> \end{CD} be a span. By the universal property for products, we have a unique map $p: R \implies A \times B.$
>
> We make a matrix of natural numbers out of this data as follows. The set of rows is $A$, the set of columns is $B$. For $a \in A, b \in B$, the $(a, b)$ entry is the cardinality of its preimage, $|p^{-1}(ab)|$, i.e., the number of elements in $R$ that are sent by $p$ to $(a, b)$.

Let $A = \{1, 2\}, B = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and consider the span

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @<f<< R\\
    & @VV g V\\
      && B
\end{CD}

given by the table

\begin{array}{|c|c c|}
\hline
 & R  \\ \hline
 ID& f: A & g:B \\ \hline
 1 &  1& 2&\\ \hline
 2 &  1& 2&\\ \hline
 3 &  1& 3&\\ \hline
 4 &  2& 1&\\ \hline
 5 &  2& 2&\\ \hline
 6 &  2& 3&\\ \hline
 7 &  2& 3&\\ \hline
 8 &  2& 3&\\ \hline
\end{array}

Then the matrix corresponding to this span is

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 2 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I am having difficuty seeing how they obtained the matrix. Can somebody, please, explain what they did to obtain the entries of the matrix. I've been stairing at it for a while now and still can't make sense of it.

Comment: In your example $R=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ and the induced map $p: R \to A\times B$ is defined by $p(1)=p(2)=(1,2)$, $p(3)=(1,3)$, $p(4)=(2,1)$, $p(5)=(2,2)$, $p(6)=p(7)=p(8)=(2,3)$. Writing $|p^{-1}(x,y)|$ for the number of elements in the preimage $p^{-1}(x,y)=\{w\in R\,|\,p(w)=(x,y)\}$ we see that:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
        |p^{-1}(1,1)| & |p^{-1}(1,2)| & |p^{-1}(1,3)| \\
        |p^{-1}(2,1)| & |p^{-1}(2,2)| & |p^{-1}(2,3)| \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 2 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: @ Nex. I guess I should've explicitely written down all the givens like you have.  I see it now. Thank you.